# Can't add to cart (custom function) when not logged

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

this function was working fine but since few days (and few updates Wp 5.9 to 6.X And others plugins) it only work when i'm logged in!.. For normal Users. the form post but the Cart is empty.. This function is used to add in bulk one ore more variation of the same product..

The function is in my child theme and was working for 1 year.. unfortunately.. i can't find a backup from before my updates!?! SHAME ON ME!!

```
function cps_add_multiple_products_to_cart() {

if ( empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart-manual'] )) {
    return;
}
global $woocommerce;    
$active_step = active_step();
$step_urls = step_urls();
//'add-to-cart' should be in this format - product_id1|variation_id1|variation_attribute1|variation_value1,product_id2|variation_id2|variation_attribute2|variation_value2 ... this is the format - product_id1|variation_id1|variation_attribute1|variation_value1,product_id2|variation_id2|variation_attribute2|variation_value2 
$product_var_ids = explode( ',', $_REQUEST['add-to-cart-manual'] ); //product with variation ids that needs to be added

foreach ( $product_var_ids as $product_var_id ) {
    $pdt_var_temp = explode( '|', $product_var_id );
    $product_id = $pdt_var_temp[0];
    $variation_id = $pdt_var_temp[1];
    $variation_attribute = $pdt_var_temp[2];
    $variation_attribute_value = $pdt_var_temp[3];
    $variation_qte = $pdt_var_temp[4];

    $pdt_in_cart = false;

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {  

        if( in_array( $values['variation_id'], $variation_id ) ) {  
            $pdt_in_cart = true;                
        }
    }

     if ( !$pdt_in_cart ) {   
        $quantity     = $variation_qte;
        if ($quantity > 0) {
            $variation    = array( $variation_attribute  => $variation_attribute_value );
           
            $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation );
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'cps_add_multiple_products_to_cart', 15 );
```

Comment: what is active_step() and step_urls() ? this is something custom.

Comment: YesI.. its 2 custom functions..  to know where we are in the process.. and links to other steps of the process..

Comment: And by the way.. I try to deactivate all plugin (except woocommerce) to test and the same problem occurs..  then a isuspect a change in WP 5.9 to 6 and or woo..